# how to exclude search words in synonyms filter in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

While I'm adding table and tables as synonym filter in elastic search, I need to filter out the results for table fan. How to achieve this in elastic search

Could we build a taxonomy of inclusion and exclusion lists filters in settings rather than at run time queries in elastic search

Comment: You want to exclude "table fan" , "tables fan", "table and fan", "tables and fan" ?

Comment: yes exactly....

Comment: Please check ...

Comment: @AnoopGeorge did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :)

Comment: @BhavyaGupta I was looking for settings rather than query time filters. I'm having large set of data and this one is just a sample one. the query time filtering will have higher performance impact as I need to filter out the exclusion filter externally. I was looking similar to that of synonym filters implementation in analyzer settings

Comment: @AnoopGeorge The analyzer parameter specifies the analyzer used for text analysis when indexing or searching a text field., please refer this ES official documentation on analyzer https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analyzer.html#analyzer

Comment: @AnoopGeorge any update and luck here ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "synonym_filter": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms": [
              "table, tables"
            ]
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "synonym_analyzer": {
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "synonym_filter"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "synonym_analyzer",
        "search_analyzer": "standard"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Analyze API**

```
POST/_analyze

{
  "analyzer" : "synonym_analyzer",
  "text" : "table fan"
}
```

The following tokens are generated:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "table",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "tables",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "SYNONYM",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "fan",
      "start_offset": 6,
      "end_offset": 9,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{ "title": "table and fan" }
{ "title": "tables and fan" }
{ "title": "table fan" }
{ "title": "tables fan" }
{ "title": "table chair" }
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "match": {
                    "title": "table"
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must_not": [
                        {
                            "match_phrase": {
                                "title": "table fan"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "match_phrase": {
                                "title": "table and fan"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use [match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) in place of [match_phrase](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html) query

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "match": {
                    "title": "table"
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must_not": [
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "title": {
                                    "query": "table fan", 
                                    "operator": "AND"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "synonym",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.06783115,
        "_source": {
          "title": "table chair"
        }
      }
    ]
```

**Update 1:**

> Could we build a taxonomy of inclusion and exclusion lists filters in
> settings rather than at run time queries in elastic search

Mapping is the process of defining how a document, and the fields it contains, are stored and indexed.Refer this [ES documentation on mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html) to understand what mapping is used to define.

Please refer to this documentation on [Dynamic template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html) that allow you to define custom mappings that can be applied to dynamically added fields

Answer (score 0):

```
GET <indexName>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "match": {
            "<fieldName>": {
              "query": "table fan", // <======= Below operator will applied b/w table(&synonyms) And fan(&synonyms)
              "operator": "AND"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You can use above query to exclude all the documents having both 'table', 'fan' and their corresponding synonyms.

**OR:**

If you want to play with multiple logical operators. e.g Given me all the documents which doesn't contain either "table fan" Or "ac" you can use [simple_query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html)

```
GET <indexName>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "simple_query_string": {
            "query": "(table + fan) | ac", // <=== '+'='and', '|'='or', '-'='not' 
            "fields": [
              "<fieldName>" // <==== use multiple field names, wildcard also supported
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```